# All objects ID's are the same when pushing new elements to an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am executing the following code:

```
        dietDay.meals.forEach((meal) => {
          meal.mealProducts.forEach((mealProduct) => {
            if (
              mealProduct.product.id &&
              this.fetchedProductIds.includes(mealProduct.product.id)
            ) {
              return;
            } else if (mealProduct.product.id) {
              this.fetchedProductIds.push(mealProduct.product.id);
              this.httpClient.get(environment.backendUrl + '/products/' + mealProduct.product.id)
              .subscribe((response: any) => {
                this.products.push(response);
                this.setDaySummary();
                this.setActiveMealSummary();
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

The loop iterates through meals, and gets the product data from the backend using a GET call.

`this.products` array contains an array of objects of type Products.
In each iteration a new Product is downloaded from the backend and pushed into the array.
After running through the loop all of the Products in the array have the same ID, but all of the other properties are different.

[image]

As you can see in the console log output of the `this.products` array, two objects have the same ID, even though when I console.log output each individual response from the backend the ID's are different.

What is going on?

Comment: It looks like you are mutating data from somewhere in the code. Did you try logging `this.products` after the  `this.products.push(response)` statement?

Comment: yes, and it contains same id's even if the object pushed into this.products has a different id

Answer (score 0):

In the `this.setDaySummary()` function, I had '=' instead of '===' and it was assigning the product id.